# mysql if row doesn't exist, grab default value

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm making a preferences module for a system so users can define their own preferences for certain parts (stuff like lay-out, color-scheme, homescreen etc.). Every preference in the table has got a default value (in case the user hasn't defined one yet) and once the user has changed their preferences the system should use that user-defined value.

I'm having trouble with selecting the desired value, my query works with the user-defined value, but sadly it returns `null` when the user hasn't defined a preference yet.

I have 2 tables

```
table **preferences**:
id
name
default_value

table **preferences_defined**:
id
preference_id
user_id
defined_value
```

I want to create a function to easily select the desired value by giving the user_id of the person to whom the preference applies and the name of the preference. At the moment my query looks like this:

```
SELECT IF(ISNULL(defined_value),default_value,defined_value) AS result
FROM preferences
LEFT JOIN preferences_defined ON preferences_defined.id = preferences.id
WHERE user_id = 17
AND name = "menu_items"
```

I guess the `WHERE user_id = 17` part is where things go wrong because when there is no defined value available it means there also isn't a column named user_id.
I need to find a way to make this work.
**So, I need to select the defined value if it exist (given the `user_id` and the `name` of the preference), if not, it will have to return the default value.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE (user_id = 17 OR user_id IS NULL) AND name = "menu_items"`

And just to clean up the rest of the query:

The `id` in preferences defined doesn't need to be there, use a combined key of `preference_id` and `user_id` instead.

If the `id` of `preferences` was named `preference_id`, the long `ON` statement could be replaced with `USING(preference_id)`

The `IF` function can be replaced with `COALESCE(defined_value, default_value)`

Comment: Thank you, that was exacly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If I where you I would do one/two queries.

So you would get:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM preferences_defined WHERE user_id = 17 AND name = 'menu_items'"
```

And then in PHP:

```
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($rows == 0){
$query = "SELECT * FROM preferences WHERE name = 'menu_items'"}
```

This way your right query will always be in the $query var.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I'd prefer do to it without the second step